# How to solve the following multivariable optimization?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, linear-programming

I found a question in the CSIR NET exam which was an optimization problem.We have to find maximum and minimum value of $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=30x_1+90x_2+100x_3+120x_4$ subject to the constraints $x_1,x_2\geq 1,x_3,x_4\geq 1/2$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=5$.I have done Linear programming problems but this seems to be a multivariable linear programming.Can someone give me an idea how to solve it?

Comment: You may not be able to solve this graphically but the standard linear programming optimization methods (like the simplex method) are still applicable, not matter how many variables there are.

Comment: @Vasili Simplex method is too much involved.Is there no other way?

Comment: I would choose $x_1$ as large as possible, since the coefficient is the smallest. The minimum values for $x_2,x_3$ and $x_4$ are $1,\frac12, \frac12$. Thus, to minimize f we choose $x_1=3$

Comment: You can reduce the number of variables to 3 by expressing $x_4=5-x_1-x_2-x_3$ and set $ x_1+x_2+x_3 \le  4.5 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution $x=(3,1,0.5,0.5)$ obtained via inspection by @callculus42 is indeed optimal, with objective value $30\cdot3+90\cdot1+100\cdot0.5+120\cdot0.5 = 290$.  For a short certificate of optimality (from LP duality), note that
\begin{align}
30 x_1 + 90 x_2 + 100 x_3 + 120 x_4
&= 30 \sum_{j=1}^4 x_j + 60 x_2 + 70 x_3 + 90 x_4 \\
&\ge 30 \cdot 5 + 60\cdot 1 + 70\cdot0.5 + 90\cdot0.5 \\
&= 290.
\end{align}